# How to respond with an image using Vapor?

Tags: swift, vapor

I just want to have a controller action that is basically doing the same as accessing an image directly through the `Public/` folder. The difference is that the route can be whatever you want and the returned image will be the one that is determined inside of the controller function. But how to create a proper response?

My approach looks like this:

```
import Vapor

final class ImageController {
    func read(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<Data> {
        let directory = DirectoryConfig.detect()
        let promise = req.eventLoop.newPromise(Data.self)
        req.eventLoop.execute {
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: directory.workDir)
                    .appendingPathComponent("Public", isDirectory: true)
                    .appendingPathComponent("image.png"))
                promise.succeed(result: data)
            } catch {
                promise.fail(error: error)
            }
        }
        return promise.futureResult
//        try req.content.encode(data, as: .png)
    }
}
```

But it seems to me I'm overcomplicating it, do I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two additional approaches:

1. A route using Leaf to deploy the image:

   ```
   route.get("/my/random/route") {
        request -> Future<View> in
        return try request.view().render("image", ["imgname":"image.png"])
   }
   ```

With image.leaf containing:

```
<img src="#(imgname)">
```

2. A re-direct to the original location in `Public`:

   ```
   route.get("/my/random/route") {
       request -> Response in
       return request.redirect(to: "/image.png")
   }
   ```

Answer (score 10):

**But how to create a proper response?**

Directly create a **`Response`** and set the **`MediaType`**: `request.makeResponse(data, as: MediaType.png)`

Example:

```
struct ImageController: RouteCollection {
    func boot(router: Router) throws {
        let imageRoutes = router.grouped("images")
        // GET /images/get-test-image
        imageRoutes.get("get-test-image", use: getTestImage)    
    }

    func getTestImage(_ request: Request) throws -> Response {
        // add controller code here 
        // to determine which image is returned
        let filePath = "/path/to/image18.png"
        let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)

        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileUrl)
            // makeResponse(body: LosslessHTTPBodyRepresentable, as: MediaType)
            let response: Response = request.makeResponse(data, as: MediaType.png)
            return response
        } catch {
            let response: Response = request.makeResponse("image not available")
            return response
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you know how to make the same in Vapor 4?