# How to upload and download image file in Vapor 3

Tags: swift, vapor

Just started learning Vapor and cannot find this anywhere:

I need to upload the image file to the server, do some image processing, return processed image back to iOS. (No need to store it with db)

I don't need to display it with Leaf, or anything, the file is sent directly from the app and back to the app.

I couldn't find any image upload/download examples on the net with Vapor3.

Can anyone please provide me some guidance.

Comment: A non-leaf approach to sending an image: [How to respond with an image using Vapor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51975381/how-to-respond-with-an-image-using-vapor/51989950#51989950)

Comment: Uploading is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51476048/image-upload-in-vapor-3-using-postgresql